# Escaping double quote in Common Lisp

Tags: string, escaping, common-lisp, string-concatenation

How to escape double quotes while concatenating a string?
For example i hoped

```
(concatenate 'string "Mama said: " "\"Son, your life is an open book...\"")
```

to give:

```
"Mama said: "Son, your life is an open book...""
```

but instead returned it with backslashes as:

```
"Mama said: \"Son, your life is an open book...\""
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The returned value is printed readably, that is, using a representation that can be parsed with [READ](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rd_rd.htm) into a CL object. If you use a function like [PRINC](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_wr_pr.htm) which prints a string as-is you will see that the quoting did what you wanted (the outer quotes are not part of the string):

```
CL-USER> (princ (concatenate 'string "Mama said: " "\"Son, your life is an open book...\""))
Mama said: "Son, your life is an open book..."
"Mama said: \"Son, your life is an open book...\""
```

The first line is the result of PRINC, the second one of the PRINT part of the READ-EVAL-PRINT-LOOP.